# window.open MS Edge/IE slow performance

Tags: javascript, performance, internet-explorer, window.open, microsoft-edge

Opening a new window then manipulating DOM within that new window from the original window performs very slow in IE.

Chrome and FF do not have this issue.

I have verified that this occurs with MS Edge, IE11 and IE9.

Has anyone ran into this before and know of the root cause or a possible fix in MS browsers?

Here is a fiddle to replicate the issue (may have to disable popup blocker):
http://jsfiddle.net/aw2basc/5mb9eqrh/

*The code below is purely for demonstration purposes only*
(to show how slow it's rendering in a new window)

```
/*
<div id="container">
    <div id="main"></div>
</div>
*/

var someArray = Array.apply(0,Array(1000)).map(function(e,i){return i%10}),
    newWindow = window.open('http://fiddle.jshell.net/','newwin','width=530,height=420'),
    content = document.getElementById('container').innerHTML;

function addStuff(document){
    var main = document.getElementById('main');
    someArray.forEach(function(e){
        var ele = document.createElement('div');
        ele.innerHTML = e;
        ele.style.float = 'left';
        main.appendChild(ele);
    });
}

addStuff(window.document);

setTimeout(function(){
    newWindow.document.body.innerHTML = content;
    addStuff(newWindow.document);
},4000);
```

**tl;dr**
Minuplating DOM in an external window in IE is just slow; no one can explain why, and there is no fix.
Either don't work between windows with js and use the server to talk back and fourth; or make as 'few' updates as you possibly can, and just live with the delays...

Comment: Well appending to the document in a for loop is normally slow.

Comment: I work on the Edge team, and would be happy to help identify areas in which we can improve. As @epascarello stated, making numerous DOM writes in a loop isn't a good idea. Have you tried creating a [`documentFragment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment) instead, and appending that *after* the loop?

Comment: Thanks for your reply!

_The above code is purely for demonstration purposes only._

If you run [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aw2basc/5mb9eqrh/) (may have to disable popup blocker), you will see that in any MS browser, it draws all the elements on the main window without any noticeable performance impact; on the **second window** it is obviously **slow**.

Chrome and FF run in a separate window with the same performance as the main window.

If it performed poorly in both windows, I would be cool with it being an optimization thing...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably because you are creating new elements and then adding them to the DOM tree one after another in a loop, this is going to result in slow performance on all browsers. It just won't affect all browsers as drastically depending on the level of optimisation made to the functions you are using.

This would be a better method:

```
function addStuff(document){
    var main = document.getElementById('main');
    var html = '';

    someArray.forEach(function(e){
        html += '<div style="float: left;">' + e + '</div>';
    });

    main.innerHTML += html;
}
```

Comment: You are absolutely correct in saying the dom elements shouldn't be added one after another; instead they should be added all at once.  The issue is when you compare the performance of doing my poorly optimized dom additions in the main window with a new window created with window.open.  It's **really slow** in **MS browsers**...

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking of me.